# type 'ThirdViewController' does not conform to protocol UITableViewDataSource

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have started my first app, and I want the app to have a view that works as a to-do list, however, I'm getting **type 'ThirdViewController' does not conform to protocol UITableViewDataSource** as an error in my code. I already looked at a similar thread but found no solution there

```
import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  
{
    var list = ["Math Homework", "English Project", "Bio Quiz"]

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return list.count
    }

    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in the Apple Developer documentation, you need the following methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

You instead used these:

```
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

Remove `public` from both methods and it should work. Also, add `_` before `tableView:`.

Reference:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource

**EDIT:**
The methods that I described are for Swift 3. In case you are using Swift 2.3, these should be your methods:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

Almost the same that you used in the first place, but without `public`.

Comment: That cleared the error, but now I'm getting "Use of undeclared type 'IndexPath'. How do I fix this?

Comment: In which line are you receiving that error? Also, 'indexPath' should start with a lower case 'i'.

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell   -- in both of your suggested edits I'm getting the same error

Comment: Ah ok, you are using Swift 2.3 instead of Swift 3. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the required protocol methods for UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate.

you are missing;

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```